# »Es geht kein Weg zurück« or »Es gibt keinen Weg zurück«? Which one is correct?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

When you want to say “There’s no way back (in life)”, like when you do something, it cannot be undone. Should I use: “Es geht” or “Es gibt”?

I once asked a friend of mine from Austria, she tried to make me understand but I still don’t know which one is the correct way to say with that meaning.

Comment: A simple Google search shows hundreds of hits. You can take any dictionary and a lot of textbooks discuss this topic. Finally, since it is a very common pattern, you find it all over the web anyway. Thus general reference. — That being said, "Es geht" isn't wrong per se but it's just not the right translation for "there is".

Comment: _Es gibt kein Zurück_ is probably most idiomatic, also possible: _es führt kein Weg zurück_.

Comment: Is that oldfashioned?

Answer (score 1):

Both versions are correct and good German, and you can use both to translate “There is no way back”. But there are subtile differences:

> Es gibt keinen Weg zurück.

is a more verbatim translation. It respects the grammar and word order of the English original. Here you have almost a word-to-word translation. The literal word-to-word translation back to english is:

> It is no way back.

But since “it is” is not correct English, you use “there is”.

Let's look at the other sentence:

> Es geht kein Weg zurück.

word by word:

> It/there goes no way back.

I'm not absolutely sure, but as far as I know ways can't go anywhere in English. People walking on them can go somewhere, but the way itself doesn't go. In German this is different. You can say (in brackets: word-by-word translations):

> Dieser Weg geht nach Norden. (This way goes to north.)
>   Die Straße geht bergab. (The street goes downhill.)

This does not mean, that the way or street itself is moving to the north or downhills. It means, that someone who follows the way or street can go there.

So, in opposite, if (in German) no way goes to a certain target, then this means exactly the same as “there is no way to this target”.

Conclusion:
Both sentences are correct and mean the same, but one of them is grammatically closer to its English counterpart, but this doesn't really count when you see just the German result.